# Copy files from one folder to another with matching names in .txt file

Tags: python, r, shell

I want to copy files from one big folder to another folder based on matching file names in a `.txt` file.

My `list.txt` file contains file names:

```
S001
S002
S003
```

and another big folder contains many files for ex. `S001, S002, S003, S004, S005`.

I only want to copy the files from this big folder that matches the file names in my `list.txt` file.

I have tried Bash, Python - not working.

```
for /f %%f in list.txt do robocopy SourceFolder/ DestinationFolder/ %%f
```

is not working either.

My logic in Python is not working:

```
import os
import shutil

def main():

    destination = "DestinationFolder/copy"

    source = "SourceFolder/MyBigData"

    with open(source, "r") as lines:
        filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)

    for filenames in os.walk(destination):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename in filenames_to_copy:
                shutil.copy(source, destination)
```

Any answers in Bash, Python or R?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what part specifically about the Python attempt is not working?

Comment: Where you want to copy? In another folder?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy the matching file names in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your Python code is that with `os.walk()` your `filename` will be a list everytime, which will not be found in your filenames_to_copy.

I'd recommend trying with `os.listdir()` instead as this will return a list of the names of filenames/folders as strings - easier to compare against your filenames_to_copy.

Other note - perhaps you want to do `os.listdir()` (or `os.walk()`) on the source instead of the destination. Currently, you're only copying files from the source to the destination if the file already exists in the destination.

Comment: Yes, i have tried os.walk on source (sorry for the mistake above) but it is still not working.. not even with os.listdir()

Comment: Thank you @JezMonkey for your help! I got the script working now!

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk()` will return a tuple of three elements: the name of the current directory inspected, the list of folders in it, and the list of files in it. You are only interested in the latter. So your should iterate with:

```
for _, _, filenames in os.walk(destination):
```

As pointed out by JezMonkey, `os.listdir()` is easier to use as it will list of the files and folders in the requested directory. However, you will lose the recursive search that `os.walk()` enables. If all your files are in the same folder and not hidden in some folders, you'd rather use `os.listdir()`.

The second problem I see in you code is that you copy `source` when I think you want to copy `os.path.join(source, filename)`.

Can you publish the exact error you have with the Python script so that we can better help you.

**UPDATE**

You actually don't need to list all the files in the source folder. With `os.path.exists` you can check that the file exists and copy it if it does.

```py
import os
import shutil

def main():
    destination = "DestinationFolder/copy"
    source = "SourceFolder/MyBigData"

    with open("list.txt", "r") as lines: # adapt the name of the file to open to your exact location.
        filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)

    for filename in filenames_to_copy:
        source_path = os.path.join(source, filename)
        if os.path.exists(source_path):
            print("copying {} to {}".format(source_path, destination))
            shutil.copy(source_path, destination)
```

Comment: The script is not showing any error but doing nothing!

Comment: I think this problem should be easily solved by command line on ubuntu , but I am unable to figure out the code..

Comment: Are all your source files in the same folder or are they in different folder? In the second case, do you want to copy them all in the same folder or would you like keep the source architecture?

Comment: @HKS could you add a print statement in various parts of the loops to print the `filename` - this will let you see what you are looping through.

Comment: in one directory - i have a big folder with may files - but i do not want all, I only want only files that matches my file names in list.txt file. The list.txt file, big folder containing all files, destination folder is in that one directory that I mentioned in starting..

Comment: yes, it is printing the file names that are in big_directory, and the ones that I want to copy, but is not actually copying the files..

Comment: If you know where exactly are your files, then you don't need to list all files in your source folder. You can just check it exists and copy it if it does. See the update of my question for an example of how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code -

```
import glob

big_dir = "~\big_dir"
copy_to = "~\copy_to"
copy_ref = "~\copy_ref.txt"

big_dir_files = [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(big_dir, '*'))]
print 'big_dir', big_dir_files # Returns all filenames from big directory

with open(copy_ref, "r") as lines:
    filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)
    print filenames_to_copy   # prints filename which you have in .txt file

    for file in filenames_to_copy:
        if file in big_dir_files:   # Matches filename from ref.txt with filename in big dir
            file_to_copy = os.path.join(big_dir, file)
            copy_(file_to_copy, copy_to)

def copy_(source_dir, dest_dir):
    files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*'))
    for file in files:
        dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file)))
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.mkdir(dest)
        shutil.copy2(file, dest)
```

Reference:

***https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html***

Comment: This script is printing both the files - all file names in big_dir, as well as - file names in copy_ref.txt file.. Error is : File "copy.py", line 18, in <module>
    shutil.copy(big_dir, copy_to)
  File "/home/heena/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/home/heena/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

Comment: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: "~\big_dir"

Comment: So you are getting the desired files, now only problem is in copy. Right?

Comment: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/MyDir/All-samples/S011837

Comment: I noticed! Still getting the same error: with different file names each time:

Comment: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: /MyDir/All-samples/S011919'

Comment: @HKS Can you let me know what you are getting in "file" in code ```if file in big_dir_files:```

Comment: I am getting S011357 - the first name of the file in copy_ref.txt

Comment: and then I am getting this error: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/MyDir/AllSamples/S011357

Comment: Are you sure that S011357  is filename not directory?

Comment: file to copy - is also correct -  /MyDir/AllSamples/S007313 - the next file

Comment: It is a folder that also contains other files, but I want to copy the whole folder..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @PySaad and @Guillaume for your contributions, although my script is working now: I added:

```
             if os.path.exists(copy_to):
            shutil.rmtree(copy_to)
            shutil.copytree(file_to_copy, copy_to)
```

to the script and its working like a charm :)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Although I would really like to hear more on the bash script. I think there should be a one line bash script to do this task something like I did but it is not working so I will work on it too..

Comment: You can try on robocopy(windows) or cp(linux) in subprocess.call() that work quiet fast when you have large number of file

Comment: I tried to upvote the answers.. But I am not able to see if I did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an overkill `bash` script/tool. Check https://github.com/jordyjwilliams/copy_filenames_from_txt out.

This can be invoked by `./copy_filenames_from_txt.sh -f ./text_file_with_names -d search_dir-o output_dir`

The script can be summarised (without error handling/args etc) to:

```bash
cat $SEARCH_FILE | while read i; do
    find $SEARCH_DIR -name "*$i*" | while read file; do
        cp -r $file $OUTPUT_DIR/
    done
done
```

The 2nd `while` loop here is not even strictly necessary... One could just pass $i to the `cp`. (eg a list of files if multiple matches) I just wanted to have each file handled separately for the tool I was writing...

To make this a bit nicer and add error handling...

The active part of the my tool in the repo is (ignore the color markers):

```bash
cat $SEARCH_FILE | while read i; do
    # Handle non-matching file
    if [[ -z $(find $SEARCH_DIR -name "*$i*") && $VERBOSE ]]; then
        echo -e "❌: ${RED}$i${RESET} ||${YELLOW} No matching file found${RESET}"
        continue
    fi
    # Handle case of more than one matching file
    find $SEARCH_DIR -name "*$i*" | while read file; do
        if [[ -n "$file" ]]; then  # Check file matching
            FILENAME=$(basename ${file}); DIRNAME=$(dirname "${file}")
            if [[ -f $OUTPUT_DIR/"$FILENAME" ]]; then
                if [[ $DIRNAME/ != $OUTPUT_DIR && $VERBOSE ]]; then
                    echo -e ": ${CYAN}$FILENAME ${GREEN}already exists${RESET} in ${MAGENTA}$OUTPUT_DIR${RESET}"
                fi
            else
                if [[ $VERBOSE ]]; then
                    echo -e "✅: ${GREEN}$i${RESET} >> ${CYAN}$file${RESET} >> ${MAGENTA}$OUTPUT_DIR${RESET}"
                fi
                cp -r $file $OUTPUT_DIR/
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).